# How to get Bluetooth connected or paired event Programmatically (iOS 7)

Tags: ios

How to get Bluetooth connected or paired event Programmatically (iOS 7)
Please reply i need Status of Bluetooth Paired/connected or not.

Thanks

Comment: In general, programming belongs on stack overflow. Have a look at the [help]. If you edit this to make it about terminal scripting, we can consider re-opening it.